# Subsonic 2 Order By sorting not working

Tags: sql-order-by, subsonic2.2

I am trying to sort (ORDER BY ) a subsonic DAL collection

```
New templateController.FetchAll().OrderByDesc("Name")
```

But it is not sorting. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Used this as a solution

```
New SubSonic.Select().From(Templatedata.Schema).OrderAsc("Name").ExecuteTypedList(Of Templatedata)()
```